When is a morphism between the frame bundles the differential of a smooth function?
Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds, and let $\Phi:\text{Fr}(TM)\to \text{Fr}(TN)$ be a principal bundle morphism.
Clearly $\Phi$ determines an unique map $\phi:M\to N$ such that $\pi_N\circ \Phi=\phi\circ\pi_M$ where $\pi_M,\pi_N$ are the frame bundle projections.
Clearly not always $\Phi=d\phi$. For example if
$$M=N=\mathbb{R},\ \ \ \ \phi=0.$$
then $\text{Fr}(TM)=\text{Fr}(TN)\cong \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^\ast$ (where $\mathbb{R}^\ast:=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$) and the map $\Phi(x,g)=(0,g)$ is such that $\pi_N\circ \Phi=\phi\circ \pi_M$.
My question is the following

Under what conditions $\Phi$ is the differential of the smooth function $\phi:M\to N$?


Once you replace "a" with "the" in your question (as you should), the answer will be immediate.

@MoisheKohan I did but the answer is still not immediate to me.

Note btw that $\Phi$ can’t really be the differential/tangent map of $\phi$, since $T\phi:TM\to TN$. Rather, if $\dim M=\dim N$ and $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism, then $\phi$ induces a natural map $R\phi:RM\to RN$ (where I denote $RM:=\text{Fr}(TM)$) by $(R\phi)(r_x):=(T\phi_x)\circ r_x$ (here I’m viewing a frame on a vector space $V$ as an isomorphism $\Bbb{R}^{\dim V}\to V$). Note that it is important that $\phi$ be a local diffeomorphism, otherwise $(T\phi)_{r_x}\circ r_x$ need not be a frame for $N$ at $f(x)$, so we can only say that $RM$ is mapped into $\text{Hom}(N\times\Bbb{R}^n;TN)$
So our question now becomes when can $\Phi$ equal $R\phi$. Before we answer this, let us record some properties of $R$ which are immediate from the definition (via the chain rule):

if $f:M\to N$ and $g:N\to P$ are local diffeomorphisms, then $R(g\circ f)=(Rg)\circ (Rf)$. Also, $R(\text{id}_M)=\text{id}_{RM}$. In particular if $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, so is $Rf$, and if $f$ is a diffeomorphism then so is $Rf$, with $(Rf)^{-1}=R(f^{-1})$.
if $f:M\to N$ is a local diffeomorphism then $Rf$ has the correct equivariance property, so $Rf:RM\to RN$ is a principal bundle morphism over $f$.
if $f:M\to N$ is a local diffeomorphism and $\sigma_M,\sigma_N$ are the soldering forms on $RM,RN$ respectively, then $(Rf)^*(\sigma_N)=\sigma_M$.

The last bullet point motivates, and is contained in, the following result (again, it’s an exercise in Dieudonne).

Theorem.
Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds of the same dimension, and let $\Phi:RM\to RN$ be a principal bundle morphism (which is equivariant relative to the usual right actions on the frame bundles) and having a base map $\phi$ that is a local diffeomorphism. Then, $\Phi=R\phi$ if and only if $\Phi^*(\sigma_N)=\sigma_M$.

To prove this result, let us just compute what this pullback is. For any frame $r_x\in RM$, we have
\begin{align}
(\Phi^*\sigma_N)_{r_x}&:=(\sigma_N)_{\Phi(r_x)}\circ T\Phi_{r_x}\\
&:=\Phi(r_x)^{-1}\circ T(\pi_N)_{\Phi(r_x)}\circ T\Phi_{r_x}\\
&=\Phi(r_x)^{-1}\circ T(\pi_N\circ \Phi)_{r_x}\tag{chain rule}\\
&=\Phi(r_x)^{-1}\circ T(\phi\circ\pi_M)_{r_x}\\
&=\Phi(r_x)^{-1}\circ T\phi_{x}\circ (T\pi_M)_{r_x}\tag{chain rule}\\
&:= \Phi(r_x)^{-1}\circ T\phi_{x}\circ r_x\circ (\sigma_M)_{r_x}\\
&:=\Phi(r_x)^{-1}\circ (R\phi)(r_x)\circ (\sigma_M)_{r_x}
\end{align}
Note that $(\sigma_M)_{r_x}:=r_x^{-1}\circ (T\pi_M)_{r_x}$ is a surjective linear map. Therefore, $(\Phi^*\sigma_N)_{r_x}=(\sigma_M)_{r_x}$ if and only if the composition in front equals $\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$, i.e if and only if $\Phi(r_x)= (R\phi)(r_x)$. Since $r_x\in RM$ was arbitrary, this shows $\Phi=R\phi$ if and only if $\Phi^*(\sigma_N)=\sigma_M$.

(and the use of $R$ as the notation I’m guessing comes from German since Google says that “frame” translates into “rahmen”)

Thank you very much! :)

but I should say that I’m not sure how useful this is ‘in practice’, because as you can see from the proof, the result is pretty much tautological
